# How can I convert .odt to .html (or .md) from the commandline?

Tags: conversion, libreoffice, odt

I'm looking for [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) that can convert [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) to HTML or markdown.

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert HTML to OpenDocument, but not the reverse.

[odt2html.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odt2html.py/1.1) failed to install using both `pip` and `easy_install`.

[LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters) can reportedly do the conversion; however, I couldn't get it to work with the following command:

```
soffice --convert-to --outdir . htm:HTML my.odt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `--convert-to`, but you're not specifying the value for it.

The correct syntax is:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to htm:HTML --outdir . my.odt
```

Or try to use [the following script](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-convert-doc-and-odf-files-to-clean-and-lean-html/):

```
#! /bin/bash

CONFIG=/path/to/tidy_options.conf
# rm -rv "$2"
mkdir -p "$2"

for F in `find $1 -type f -name "*.doc" -or -name "*.odt"`; do
  BASE=`basename $F .doc` ; BASE=`basename $BASE .odt`
  soffice --headless --convert-to htm:HTML --outdir $2 $F
  tidy -q -config $CONFIG -f $2/$BASE.err -i $2/$BASE.htm | sed 's/ class="c[0-9]*"//g' > $2/$BASE.html
done
```

Usage:

```
$ convert_doc_to_html.sh SOURCE_DIR TARGET_DIR
```

See:

- [How to convert .doc and ODF files to clean and lean HTML](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-convert-doc-and-odf-files-to-clean-and-lean-html/) at TechRepublic

Comment: Right! I copied the command from somewhere else and I hadn't noticed the problem with syntax because of the `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/` part. Thanks.

Comment: I had to change `--convert-to htm:HTML` to just `--convert-to html`. Otherwise, I got no output file at all. Plus 1, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

New versions of [pandoc](https://pandoc.org), the open source universal document converter, work now:

```
pandoc -t html -s input.odt -s -o output.html
```

Comment: Update 2022: my `pandoc` command insists that I also add `--metadata pagetitle="..."` (even tough there _is_ a `title` property set in the docx file)

Comment: Update 2024: `pandoc` will make a default title now if there is none.